# Pool.Apply_Async won't loop, ValueError: Pool not running

Tags: python-3.x, loops, multiprocessing

This is what I have for multiprocessing, It runs nice really speeding up. However, it won't loop to second page. gives me "ValueError: Pool not running."

```
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) '
                      'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                      'Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36 QIHU 360SE'
    }
    response = requests.get(forum_page_url, headers=headers).content
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
    recommended = soup.select('tbody:has(.threadpages [src="images/new.gif"]), '
                              'tbody:has(.threadpages [src="images/new1.gif"]), '
    for item in recommended:
        for i in item.select('.folder [href^="thread-"]'):
            url_tail = i['href']
            url_domain = 'http://www.pop999.com/forum/'
            url = urljoin(url_domain, url_tail)
            # 多线程 Multiprocessing
            # q = multiprocessing.Queue()
            p.apply_async(download_imgs, args=(url, ))
            p.apply_async(retrieve_bt_link, args=(url, ))
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

my close and join are lined up with the first for loop, It just won't process to the second page, returning "ValueError: Pool not running." Does anyone have an idea why and how?

problem is fixed when I combined with previous loop function(abbrev version):

```
    forum pages ranging loops:
        posts for loops:
            p.apply_async
            p.apply_async
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

from my point of understanding is that, if you have more than 2 loops in a hierarchy order {mine is forum loop >> post loop >> file loop}(not parallel), and you wanna loop them with multiprocessing. I highly suggest you to combine them together in one function to avoid "pool not running" ValueError.

you can do multiprocessing for each functions, I am just not sure yet if it works. I also met with "daemonic process does not allow child process" few times earlier. So, see how it would work to fit your situation then.

PS my skill in (CS)python is very limited, so my suggestions are not for everyone. This is very basic stuff.

Comment: queue and manager seems not to be the case, queue didn't help, it just parsed all post_links, without downloading anything, and terminated my codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is solved with a minor fix:

my codes contain three major parts:
1. Multiple forum page selection,
2. posts collection,
3. posts content photo & seed download.

the "ValueError: Pool not running" happens if I write 2 functions for forum & post each, both of them has a loop, ranging loop for multiple page, and for loop for posts. problem solved when i merged them together as one function.